# Scala-Spray: How to merge JsArray elements

Tags: scala, spray-json

I have two `JsArray`s representing these two json feeds:

```
[{
  "value1":"foo",
  "value2":"bar"
}, {...}]

[{
  "value3":"foo2",
  "value4":"bar2"
}, {...}]
```

How can I merge only the first element of each one to get:

```
{
  "value1":"foo",
  "value2":"bar",
  "value3":"foo2",
  "value4":"bar2"
}
```

using `spray.json` ?

Answer (score 0):

(array1.convertTo[Map[String,JsValue]] ++ array2.convertTo[Map[String,JsValue]]).toJson.asJsArray

Assuming array1 and array2 are JsArray

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add an explanation as to why your answer will work. Code alone doesn't make a complete answer